# Trouble sending/receiving strings for client/server

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I am having a little bit of trouble sending and receiving strings from client to server. Assume I have the sockets set up correctly.
This is what I am using to send/receive server side:

```
fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
toClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

String clientInput;
clientInput = fromClient.readLine();
```

is how my server receives inputs from the client.

Client side same deal:

```
toServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine(); //inputLine reads from the console
toServer.write(inputLine);
```

I can send a message to the sever and it will receive it but when I uncomment out this bit for the client to receive a response from the server:

```
//        serverInput = fromServer.readLine();
//
//        System.out.println(serverInput);
```

It will hang and the server side wont receive the initial message sent. I have no idea whats wrong and I just want to get a reply from the server. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you call `toClient.write(clientInput)` at the server side?

Comment: after clientInput = fromClient.readLine();, I print clientInput and it will print it. But if I use "toClient.write("recieve this please");" after and uncomment the bit out on the client side, it will hang and not even receive the initial message

Comment: nevermind.... I figured it out. I had to add a + '\n' in the write parameter and then do a flush afterwards.

Comment: Exactly, I saw your comment while I am writing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**`BufferedReader.readLine()` will strip the newline character for you.**

That means, at client side, `inputLine` does not have a trailing `\n`, which means the client did not send the end of line signal to the server and vice versa.

**Client Side**

```
toServer.write(...);
toServer.newLine(); // <--- send new line
toServer.flush();   // <--- flush buffered data
```

Server should do the similar thing.